# When hit by an attack that deals direct damage and splash damage, do vulnerability effects apply to both instances of damage separately?

Tags: pathfinder-2e, vulnerability

Let's say, I throw an [Dwarven Daisy](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=594)<sup>1</sup> at a creature that is weak to Fire. The bomb deals direct fire damage to its target, and also Fire Splash damage.

If the target is vulnerable to fire, is the damage of both the direct *and* the splash increased by the vulnerability (effectively double dipping in this case)?

<sup>1</sup> Chosen because it does both fire damage and fire splash damage, but has no persistent damage for the sake of simplicity.

Answer (score 8):

## You Trigger the Weakness Once

From the [Splash Trait rules](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=704):

> "Add splash damage together with the initial damage against the target before applying the target's resistance or weakness"

Comment: I knew I had remembered seeing that language somewhere and I couldn’t find it for the life of me. Thanks!